# What does a CONSTRAINT have to do with my unique index?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index, constraint, ddl

I have to indexes on my table.  The first was created by Django and the second by me. I'm not completely certain what the extra `CONSTRAINT` means in the first index and am wondering how I would change my `CREATE INDEX` statement to add that to it.

```
"customers_phonetype_customer_id_176731583d230ba5_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (customer_id, display) ;-- Django created
"customers_phonetype_customer_id_uniq" UNIQUE, btree (customer_id, lower(display::text)) ; -- Manually created
```

This is how I manually created the second index:

```
create unique index customers_phonetype_customer_id_uniq on customers_phonetype (customer_id, lower(display));
```

What is the meaning of the extra word `CONSTRAINT` in this case? I'm not seeing it in the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createindex.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is a unique **constraint**. It can be *added* to an existing table with:

```
ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT ...
```

[Details in the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html).
It is *implemented* using a unique index. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS)

> Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique btree
>   index on the column or group of columns used in the constraint. A
>   uniqueness constraint on only some rows can be enforced by creating a partial index.

In addition it allows [foreign key](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) references to it.

The second one in a unique **index**.
It couldn't be a unique constraint because those only allow columns, not expressions. More details:

- [How does PostgreSQL enforce the UNIQUE constraint / what type of index does it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067108/939860)
- [Discussion on pgsql-general](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/F8E84F0F56445B4CB39E019EF67DACBA48C253@exchsrvr.winemantech.com#F8E84F0F56445B4CB39E019EF67DACBA48C253@exchsrvr.winemantech.com) about the difference between constraint and index.