# Get result from select exists, execute insert query based on the response of it

Tags: postgresql, insert, unique-constraint, node.js

I have to insert unique value for a row but has to put check on 3 columns collectively `((unique value(col1 && col2 && col3) == true)`

I found a solution here it is

```
query = select exists(select 1 from titles where "col1"='${col1}' AND "col2"='${col2}' AND "col3"='${col3}');
```

This query would return true or false based on the entries of the table

```
if(query == true)
```

execute `insert into table values ('col1','col2','col3','col4','col5');`

I am inserting multiple records from a json file using promises.

Is there any way to execute this in single `sequelize.query()`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `UNIQUE` index or constraint on `(col1, col2, col3)` - if you don't have one already.

Then use [`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT). That's simpler, faster and more reliable, and unlike the route you had in mind, it's also safe against race conditions.

Related:

- [What does a CONSTRAINT have to do with my unique index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95038/what-does-a-constraint-have-to-do-with-my-unique-index/95039#95039)
- [What happens with duplicates when inserting multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875185/what-happens-with-duplicates-when-inserting-multiple-rows/30878260#30878260)

Be aware of NULL handling:

- [PostgreSQL multi-column unique constraint and NULL values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/postgresql-multi-column-unique-constraint-and-null-values/9760#9760)